# How to fix "SQLite Error 1: 'The specified module could not be found." with EF and Spatialite

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, spatialite

I am creating a spatial database with EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.NetTopologySuite to store a point for now but will eventually be for lines etc. I have used the Spatial Data documentation as reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial#sqlite. The data needs to be saved into a Spatialite database.

Having been through the documentation I have reflected the code as it is stated including "UseNetTopology" in the options builder (below) and have created a Point in the class.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=TestDb.db", x => x.UseNetTopologySuite());
    }
```

When I attempt to update the database with `update-database` I receive the error:

```
SQLite Error 1: 'The specified module could not be found.'.
```

I have attempted to find the issue by creating a blank project and working from the ground up but the result comes to the same error.

Here is the whole log:

```
'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.SpatialiteLoader.Load(DbConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.LoadSpatialite()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
SQLite Error 1: 'The specified module could not be found.
'.
```

I cannot find any other post with the same issue.

**EDIT 19/8/19:**
I have just created a new blank project to test without entity framework by installing from the Spatialite website and using SQLite to connect to a spatial database. I received the same error doing it the manual way so perhaps this is an issue with Spatialite?

Comment: Hey!!! have you been able to solve this issue? I am actually running into it, I can't figure out how to deal with it!

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca Unfortunately not, I have been using Postgis since so that the rest of the project can still progress. I would still prefer to use Spatialite but I could not find an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jarb
I solved (temporarily) the issue by copying manually the content of `mod_spatialite\4.3.0.1\runtimes\win-x64\native` into the project's bin folder, in my case `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\win10-x64`

You can follow the thread on GitHub [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/17864).

Apparently there is a known issue related to this bug [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14093).